# Resolving empty collections with Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

One of my classes has a property like this:

```
ICollection<IValidationError> collection { get; set; }
```

I setup Windsor to use the CollectionResolver subresolver as such:

```
_container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new CollectionResolver(_container.Kernel, true));
```

However, Windsor gives me a `Collection<ValidationError>` object with **ONE** `ValidationError` object inside.

Is there any way to make Windsor create a simple empty collection instead?

Comment: The `container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new CollectionResolver(container.Kernel, true));` does work as expected. No need to manipulate config. Maybe you had an autoresolve setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work, if I declare an empty list as a parameter to the constructor:

```
<component id="MyClass"
           type="MyClass, WindsorSample">
  <parameters>
    <myCollection>
      <list>
      </list>
    </myCollection>
  </parameters>
</component>
```

But this is not a very clean way of doing it.
Also, it forces you to have a constructor which takes the collection as an argument.

If anyone finds a better way to accomplish this, post it and I'll mark it as accepted.